What on earth is a topological cavity in a certain simplicial complex?
I am dealing with basic algebraic topology for my research, and have been confused about topological cavities for a long time. Until now, I have already understood the concepts about k-dimensional cycles, boundaries, homological groups, Hodge decomposition in terms of Euclidean space, and k-th Betti number indicating the number of k-dimensional cavities. But what is a k-cavity of a certain simplicial complex? I have searched Google and acquired a lot of essays con neural science and mathematics, but none of them really pointed out the exact mathematical (or topological) definition of cavities.
My understanding after reading some of the essays above: The k-th homological group is a finite group which has several equivalent classes as its elements. This finite group has a finite minimum generating set, whose cardinality equals to the k-th Betti number and is exactly the rank of this finite group. A k-th cavity is any representative element of one equivalent class of the minimum generating set. Am I correct?
If anyone can provide a book that introduces the mathematical definition of topological cavities and Hodge decomposition, it will be very appreciated.

"some of the essays above" Could you please actually add some references? The term $k$-cavity does not ring familiar at all (unless you're talking about the informal notion of "$k$-dimensional holes" people sometimes use for intuition; that doesn't really have a formal mathematical definition).

It seems that the sources that you found are misleading you; in particular, there is no notion of a "topological cavity", somebody is just making it up. My suggestion is to read, for instance, Hatcher's book on algebraic topology for proper definitions.

Welcome. You're also saying "certain" simplicial complex as if you have a specific example in mind. What is that example? Echoing the other comments, there are a few ways to define (co)homology and there are various geometric motivations but they're all, at the end of the day, formal and explicit with no mention to vague notions of cavity. Words like cavity would just be labels to informally think about what homology classes are

@Ben: Some of my reference essays are link and link. To my knowledge, this term is usually referred to as "cavity", but I indeed encountered "hole" or "void" to express a "closed" topological structure surrounded by certain simplices in a simplicial complex.

@dhliu Your second link gives a definition, and further refers to this paper which gives some more detail.

@Moishe: It is surprising to me that the term "topological cavity" is made up by some researchers... So that's why I cannot search out the exact definition of this term. But in neural science the term "cavity" seems to appear a lot of times, see doi: 10.1162/netn_a_00073. Anyway thanks for your comment!

@Ben: Yes, I have investigated this paper, but still found it vague. At the bottom of page 5, the authors said "Elements of this homology group are cycle-equivalent classes, called -cavities", making it more confused to me that the authors seem to refer to the equivalent classes in homology groups as "k-cavities"... Moishe mentioned that this term is made up by someone, and I think this makes sense.

@dhliu all terms are made up. All words are made up. Literally all. I don't even understand what "proper definition" is supposed to mean. If you see such definition in some paper, then you know what it is. At least in the context of the paper. It might be unusual and annoying, I agree, but there's nothing inherently wrong with it.

@dhliu I want to say that Moishe is incorrect here since the term is so widely used, but upon reading a bit the definitions given in the two chinese papers are mutually incompatible: for one a $k$-cavity is an element of $H_k({{-}}; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ while for the other it's a (representative of a) "linearly independent cycle equivalence class [sic]", which, with a lot of goodwill one could interpret as "representative of a one of the elements in a choice of basis for $H_k({{-}}; \mathbb{Z}/2)$." How this got published is anyone's guess.

Unless this setting somehow prescribes a canonical way to pick a basis of these vector spaces, the first interpretation seems vastly more reasonable, and I suggest you carefully adopt it as a working definition until you encounter evidence to the contrary.

@Ben: I think you're right. Upon the definition of the so-called "cavity", the two Chinese papers actually contradict to each other. In my opinion, the homology group is a quotient group, and has a minimum generating set. The cardinality of this generating set is actually the corresponding Betti number, and also the rank of the homology group. Maybe the term "cavity" is initially created to describe the phenomenon of the existence of "non-trivial" equivalent classes of homology group (different from the empty set equivalent class).

I really appreciate the discussion with you@Ben, thanks a lot.
